# Unit test a custom authorizer lambda

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, aws-lambda, jestjs

I have a customized authorizer lambda which takes an event from a API Gateway and calls another internal api which validates if a user has access to a particular resource.

This API takes in a jwttoken and a id and returns back response.

I have been trying to write unit test for this lambda. I am lost as to how can I mock data - specifically the token and id.

Here is what I wrote (Jest)

```
describe('lambdaService', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.restoreAllMocks();
    });
    test('should return data', async () => {
        const response = { statusCode: 200 };
        const event = {
            "headers" : {
                'Authorization' : 'token'
            },
            "pathParameters": {
            "proxy": "/my-path/{id}"
        },
        }
        const retrieveData = jest.spyOn(authorizeResourceJWTUser, 'doGetRequest').mockResolvedValueOnce(response)

        const actualValue = await handler(event);
        expect(actualValue).toEqual(response);
    });
```

```
const {validate} = require('./helper/validateResource')

exports.handler =  async (event, context, callback) => {

    try {
        let id, token, HOST
        id = extractId(path)//some function to return id from url
        
        let response = await validate(id, token)
        callback(null,generatePolicy(...)
    } catch(error) {
        callback("Unauthorized")
    }
};

function generatePolicy {...};
```

But it fails giving 401 error since the token and the {id} is not valid.
There is no proper documentation on how can I mock this API call rather than calling the actual service

Comment: Show the code of the `handler`

Comment: @slideshowp2 : added the details.

Comment: Still, lack of details. Why did you try to mock `authorizeResourceJWTUser.doGetRequest` Remove the unrelated code and provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @slideshowp2 because doGetRequest makes a call to a custom authorize rest api which validates my token and resource id. I do not have a valid mapping for my unit tests